# Gson: deserializing arrays where elements are not of same type

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I try to deserialize json string with Gson library; 
I have the following class

```
class Foo {
    int Id;
    String Name;
}
```

and the following json string

```
{response: [123, { id: 1, name: 'qwerty'}, { id: 2, name: 'asdfgh'}, ]}
```

I try to deserialize this string so

```
Gson gson = new Gson();         
Foo[] res = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, Foo[].class);
```

But i faled cause this string contains not pure json array but object that contains field 'response' that is the array. 
And my second trouble is response contains literal '123' except Foo-objects.

And i wonder how can i avoid these problems? Wether i should parse string manually, extract array's content, remove from it unnecessary literals and feed parsing result to fromJson method or 
there are means that could help me to do it simpler?

Comment: There is no such thing as "pure" JSON arrays. RFC 7159 explicitly says that there is no requirement at all that the members of a JSON array all have to be of the same type (and what is more, your JSON is in fact not legal JSON).

Comment: ok whait is the simplest and quickest way to turn this array to "pure" (or "legal")?

Comment: Read as a `JsonElement` and filter out the unnecessary elements, and then deserialize; this is what I would recommend. Another solution would be to use the streaming API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Java type that is compatible with the json array you are trying to deserialize. You should use JsonParser to get a JsonObject and then process that JsonObject manually.

```
JsonParser p = new JsonParser();
JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject)p.parse(yourJsonString);
```

You can then process your jsonObject like this:

```
    List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<Foo>();
    JsonArray response = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("response");
    for (int i = 0; i < response.size(); i++) {
        JsonElement el = response.get(i);
        if (el.isJsonObject()) {
            Foo f = new Foo();
            JsonObject o = el.getAsJsonObject();
            int id = o.getAsJsonPrimitive("id").getAsInt();
            String name = o.getAsJsonPrimitive("name").getAsString();
            f.Id = id;
            f.Name = name;      
            foos.add(f);
        }
    }
```

Alternatively you could process the response JsonArray like this:

```
    List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<Foo>();
    JsonArray response = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("response");
    for (int i = 0; i < response.size(); i++) {
        JsonElement el = response.get(i);
        if (el.isJsonObject()) {
            JsonObject o = el.getAsJsonObject();
            Foo f = gson.fromJson(o, Foo.class);
            foos.add(f);
        }
    }
```

But you need to make sure the Foo class member names match the json property names. Yours do not because of capitalization. i.e. you need to change your Foo class to be like this:

```
class Foo {
    int id;
    String name;
}
```

Comment: In general if you were to gson.fromJson() you need to make sure your class member names match the property names in the Json String. Yours do not because of capitalization.